# onCreateView() called from where and when and what is its parameters when called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

lets assume that we have 2 activity

1: MainActivity (we call this `A`)

2: FragmetnActivity (`B`)

`A` in its layout only had a FrameLayout to hold `B`

Based on [this guid](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) when `A` is in its onCreate() the first four method of `B` would called respectively, yes??? they called one-by-one by `A` or no the `A` just call the first method and the rest execute respectively???

and about onCreateView() parameters, i know that it had 3 parameters ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))):

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

i want to now what would be the second parameters (ViewGroup container) when this method called by caller in my example???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call it manually. `onCreateView` is part of the Fragment's lifecycle and calling it and the timing is up to Android.

> i want to now what would be the second parameters (ViewGroup
>   container) when this method

is the container that will host the fragment. You usually provide it through a transaction in the `add`/`replace` methods

Comment: u mean if i had this `add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)` the `fragmentContainer` here refer to the second parameter???

Comment: yes exactly. Is the View's object referenced by that id